# What is the value of the segment $BI$ the figure below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

For reference: In the triangle $ABC$ draws the bisector, $BD, ~D ~and ~AC$, which intersects the circumference circumscribed in $E$. If $AE = 4~ and~ BE=8$, calculate $BI$.($I$ ➔ incenter of triangle $ABC$)

My progress:

My drawing
$\measuredangle ABE = \measuredangle EBC = \measuredangle EAC = \measuredangle ACE = \theta \implies \measuredangle AOC = 4\theta\\
O = orthocenter$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\measuredangle AIE=\measuredangle EAI,$ we obtain: $$BI=BE-IE=BE-AE=8-4=4.$$